# gcc error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gcc

I try to compile hello.c using gcc with `-mnop-mcount` option. But error occurs like below:

```
$ gcc -pg -mfentry -mnop-mcount -o hello hello.c
cc1: error: -mnop-mcount is not implemented for -fPIC
```

My gcc version is 7.3.0:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And my Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Somewhat related, I think: [Disable PIE and PIC defaults in gcc on ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911538/disable-pie-and-pic-defaults-in-gcc-on-ubuntu-17-04)

Answer (score 1):

gcc6 onwards generates `fpic` code by default  because of the way it's compiled in ubuntu. To disable this behaviour use the `fno-pic` flag as follows:

```
gcc -pg -mfentry -mnop-mcount -fno-pic -o hello hello.c
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a `-o` before the output file name. Also I suspect `-no-pie` may be required here as well as `-fno-pic`.