# Why does my file become a shared library instead of an executable?

Tags: executable, shared-library

I'm trying to build a SPPARKS (Sandia software) executable file following the procedure detailed here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT1RsrPkKXU

The issue is that, my final "make" file should end up as an executable, but instead it's becoming a shared library file. Is there an easy fix for this or some simple way to run a shared library file as an executable? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: See [Impossible to launch graphic executables in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871926/impossible-to-launch-graphic-executables-in-nautilus) and [Disable PIE and PIC defaults in gcc on ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911538/disable-pie-and-pic-defaults-in-gcc-on-ubuntu-17-04). tl;dr - use compile / build options `-fno-pic` and `-no-pie`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Any chance you are familiar with the SPPARKS file I mentioned? Basically, it comes as a bunch of .cpp and .h files with a few pre-defined "makefile"s. Do you know how/where these compile/build options would be implemented? Today is my first day using linux/C++, so I'm not fully clear on how to use those options.

Comment: FWIW the executable is probably not actually becoming a shared library file - just that some tools (notably the `nautilus` file manager) misidentify it as such