# Building a executable but shared library appear instead

Tags: software-installation, executable, shared-library

I am new and not familiar with Linux OS. The current OS I use is Ubuntu 19.10.

I was trying to build a SPPARKS (a software https://spparks.sandia.gov/index.html) executable by “make mpi”. The process got no error but a “shared library” file of spk_mpi instead of an “executable” file was produced.

I would appreciate any help from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: What MPI implementation are you using (OpenMPI? mpich?) and what underlying C/C++ compilers?

Comment: @steeldriver  Sorry, I do not exactly know the details. If it is possible, could you please try to install SPPARKS on your PC following the official manual? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already did ;) Please see below

Comment: Same thing happened to me when I installed Java 17 on Ubuntu 16, the files look as shared libraries instead of executable

Answer (score 1):

This is really the same issue as discussed in these previous questions:

- [Impossible to launch graphic executables in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871926/impossible-to-launch-graphic-executables-in-nautilus)

and the solution is essentially as mentioned in

- [Disable PIE and PIC defaults in gcc on ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911538/disable-pie-and-pic-defaults-in-gcc-on-ubuntu-17-04)

The challenge for your particular situation is how to pass the appropriate compiler/linker options through the MPI compiler wrappers.

On my 18.04 system, with OpenMPI version indicated by

```
$ mpicc --showme:version
mpicc: Open MPI 2.1.1 (Language: C)
```

and explicitly selecting gcc/g++ version 5, I was able to get a traditional non-PIE executable using the following command line (broken up with `\` line continuations for readibility):

```
OMPI_CC=gcc-5 OMPI_CXX=g++-5 \
OMPI_CFLAGS=-fno-pic OMPI_CXXFLAGS=-fno-pic OMPI_LDFLAGS=-no-pie \
make mpi
```

as confirmed using the `file` command:

```
$ file spk_mpi 
spk_mpi: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=284d76d1ca642cca833b31dfa028a7910e935600, not stripped
```

If you are using some other MPI implementation, you will need to figure out how to pass the appropriate flags for that.

**NB** you will probably need to run `make clean-all` first in order to remove any objects that were previously compiled without the `-fno-pic` flag.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind reply. So could you tell me how I can know the correct version of gcc/g++ corresponding to OpenMPI (Open MPI 3.1.3 is on my PC)? And when and where should I use the command line that you proposed? "If you are using some other MPI implementation", so how do I know what MPI implementation I am using?  Please forgive my ignorance. I haven't got a clear understanding of the entire system yet.

Comment: @YufanZhao if you were able to successfully build it (aside from the PIC/PIE issue) with your system's default compilers, then I would suggest omitting the first two assignments and simply running `OMPI_CFLAGS=-fno-pic OMPI_CXXFLAGS=-fno-pic OMPI_LDFLAGS=-no-pie make mpi` (after first running `make clean-all` as I mentioned). You would run these commands in place of the suggested `make mpi`.

Comment: ... I only added `OMPI_CC=gcc-5 OMPI_CXX=g++-5` because I experienced some build errors using the default gcc/g++ 7.4.0 on my system - and rather than investigating them, just guessed that they might go away with an older gcc/g++ version (since the source code appeared to be a couple of years old itself).

Comment: I followed your instructions, but after make with no build error, I got an "ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable" which is still a shared library file. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Should I need to edit the low-level Makefile.mpi?